# What is the coefficient in the differential coefficient?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

A term that apparently not used so much now is that of [Differential Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_coefficient)
But I can not understand what we mean by the term *coefficient* in this context.
So basically if $y=6x-x^2$ then the differencial coefficient is $dy/dx=6-2x$ but what part is the "coefficient"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y = 6x-x^2$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = 6-2x$.  This can be written as
$$
    dy = (6-2x)\,dx
$$
so that $6-2x$ is the “coefficient” of the differential $dx$.  Not coincidentally, $6-2x$ is also the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

I've never heard this phrase used before.

Comment: Do you mean `6-2x`?

Comment: @Jim: yes, sorry!

Comment: So basically we just mean multiply the `6-2x` with the Δx i.e. change of x right?

Comment: multiply...to do what?  If you want the coefficient, it is what is multiplied *by* $dx$.